# Удаление элемента и в массиве и в HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

Заметил одну ошибку при "тестировании" функции `Delete`. Вобщем у меня ну совсем не получается сделать так, что бы при удалении родительского элемента удалялись и дочерние, причем и из `HTML` и из массива. При выделении к примеру только родительского элемента удаляется только один дочерний, понимаю почему, но никак по другому организовать цикл не получается. Удаляю к примеру `Ветку_1`, у нее два дочерних элемента, соответственно длина должна быть равна восьми, но она равна девяти. Помогите чем сможете, буду благодарен!

*P.S. Не обращайте внимание на все эти "страшные" действия с переменной id, попытаюсь как нибудь потом исправить эту ошибку!*

```js
var listCategories = {
  data: [

    {
      itemId: 1,
      itemName: "Ветка_1",
      itemParentId: 0,
      inputId: 'i_1',
      liId: 'l_1'
    },

    {
      itemId: 2,
      itemName: "Элемент ветки",
      itemParentId: 1,
      inputId: 'i_2',
      liId: 'l_2'
    },

    {
      itemId: 3,
      itemName: "Элемент ветки",
      itemParentId: 1,
      inputId: 'i_3',
      liId: 'l_3'
    },

    {
      itemId: 4,
      itemName: "Ветка_2",
      itemParentId: 0,
      inputId: 'i_4',
      liId: 'l_4'
    },

    {
      itemId: 5,
      itemName: "Ветка_3",
      itemParentId: 0,
      inputId: 'i_5',
      liId: 'l_5'
    },

    {
      itemId: 6,
      itemName: "Элемент ветки",
      itemParentId: 5,
      inputId: 'i_6',
      liId: 'l_6'
    },

    {
      itemId: 7,
      itemName: "Элемент ветки",
      itemParentId: 5,
      inputId: 'i_7',
      liId: 'l_7'
    },

    {
      itemId: 8,
      itemName: "Элемент ветки",
      itemParentId: 5,
      inputId: 'i_8',
      liId: 'l_8'
    },

    {
      itemId: 9,
      itemName: "Ветка_4",
      itemParentId: 0,
      inputId: 'i_9',
      liId: 'l_9'
    },

    {
      itemId: 10,
      itemName: "Ветка_5",
      itemParentId: 0,
      inputId: 'i_10',
      liId: 'l_10'
    },

    {
      itemId: 11,
      itemName: "Элемент ветки",
      itemParentId: 10,
      inputId: 'i_11',
      liId: 'l_11'
    }

  ]
}


function createTree(data, parentId) {
  parentId = parentId || 0;
  var items = data.filter(function(el) {
    return el.itemParentId == parentId;
  });
  if (items.length == 0) return null;
  var tree = $('<ul class="sortable  ui-sortable">').addClass('tree');
  tree.append(
    items.map(
      function(el) {

        var li = $('<li class="ui-state-default  ui-sortable-handle">').append(
            $('<input>').attr({type: 'checkbox', id: el.inputId})
          ).append(
            $('<label>').html(el.itemName).attr({id: el.itemId}).addClass('item')
          ).append(
            $('<a>').addClass('state')
          ).attr({id: el.liId}),
          nestedTree = createTree(data, el.itemId);
        if (nestedTree !== null) {
          li.append(nestedTree)
            .addClass('collapse');
        }
        return li;
      }
    )
  );
  return tree;
}

Array.prototype.remove = function(value) {
    var idx = this.indexOf(value);
    if (idx != -1) {
        // Второй параметр - число элементов, которые необходимо удалить
        return this.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var tree = createTree(listCategories.data);
  $('#tree').append(
    $('<input type="button" id="deleteBranch" value="Delete">')
  ).append(
    $('<input type="button" id="addBranch" value="Add">')
  ).append(tree)
            .on('dblclick', '.item',function(){
                $(this).attr("contenteditable", "true");
            })

            .on('click', '.item',function(){
                $('.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
                $(this).toggleClass('active');
            })

            .on('click', '.state',function(){
                $(this).parent().toggleClass('collapse expand');
            })


                        // ------УДАЛЕНИЕ------
            .on('click', '#deleteBranch', function() {
              var chekId = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked');
              alert(listCategories.data.length);
            
              for (var i = 0; i<chekId.length; i++){

                var id = chekId[i].getAttribute("id");
                id = id.replace('i', 'l');
                var elementId = document.getElementById(id);
                elementId.parentNode.removeChild(elementId);
                id = id.split('_');
                id = id[1];
                id - 1;
                listCategories.data.remove(listCategories.data[id]);
                for (var y = 0; y<listCategories.data.length; ++y) {
                  if (listCategories.data[y].itemParentId == id) {
                    listCategories.data.remove(listCategories.data[y]);
                  }
                }

              }
              chekId.length==0 ? alert('Перед нажатием на кнопку выделите checkbox!'):0;
              alert(listCategories.data.length);
          })

              
});
```

```css
ul.tree {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}
.active {
  background-color: orange;
}
.state {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1em;
}
.collapse > .state::after {
  content: '+';
}
.expand > .state::after {
  content: '-';
}
.collapse > ul {
  display: none;
}
.expand > ul {
  display: block;
}
.item {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#addBranch {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#deleteBranch {
  margin-rigth: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tree"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел глупейшую ошибку! Написал - `id - 1`, а нужно было присвоить id это значение, то есть `id = id - 1;`. Основная проблема исчезла!)